# How, precisely, does one "narfle" a Garthok?

Tags: languages, coneheads

In the 1993  movie *[Coneheads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coneheads_(film))*, Beldar (Dan Aykroyd) and his family (Jane Curtin and Michelle Burke) are recalled to Remulac.  He is brought before the Highmaster (Peter Aykroyd<sup>(*)</sup>), who is displeased with the results of Beldar's reconnaissance mission to Earth.

As punishment, the Highmaster, wanting to "settle things in the ancient way", declares that Beldar shall ***Narfle the Garthok***<sup>(**)</sup>.

Beldar is then then thrown into a pit with a Big Ugly Creature (presumably the Garthok) with only a hook on a stick.

Beldar, unlike the Garthok's victims before him (who last mere seconds), [kills it in a suitably humorous way](https://youtu.be/6tx_tbW05JI)<sup>(***)</sup>.

But what is the ancient meaning of "Narfle" the Highmaster is referring to? Providing entertainment to the Court is obviously part of it, but was is Beldar actually supposed to do?

- ***fight*** the Garthok?
- ***feed*** it?
- after subduing it, give it a foot rub?
- ***be torn apart and spat out*** by an irascible but otherwise vegetarian Garthok?

Given the circumstances of the movie, it seems "Narfle" might be a "[calling a rabbit a smeerp](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CallARabbitASmeerp)"<sup>(****)</sup> version of the last one. But there might be Word of God confirmation somewhere.

---

(*) All these years, I could have sworn the Highmaster was Dave Thomas.

(**)**g**narfle, **k**narfle; whatever.

(***):

> Is making a Garthok choke to death on a rock exactly kosher? Which begs the question of how one performs the Heimlich maneuver on a Garthok and lives to tell the tale.

(****) TODO: insert Usual TvTropes link warning and disclaimer here.

Comment: I always thought it was Dave Thomas as well, so I looked it up on the IMDB. It lists Dave Thomas as the Headmaster and Peter Ackroyd as Highmaster Mentot. Now I am confused. Must watch the movie again.

I think the question about Death by Narfle is entertaining, because we can all make up any answers we want, the more outrageous the better, in my opinion. Begs for a Narfle drinking game. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: I can't see anything in the script that suggests it's anything other than fight; https://www.scriptslug.com/script/coneheads-1993

Comment: I know I'm losing here, but you're not [begging the question](https://danielmiessler.com/blog/the-original-meaning-of-begging-the-question/), you're "raising the question"

Comment: https://youtu.be/JwUrdQvNN0o not an answer but the 1983 cartoon existing may be of interest to the readers of this page

Comment: @PeterM Yes, well hopefully you won't have to fight too many more of those losing battles.

Comment: While I hope to read a canonical answer, I won't be surprised if none exists. Good writers (especially of comedy) never explain stuff like this on purpose - your imagination is worth more than a thousand explanations. The fact that you're here asking what it means demonstrates the value of why writers do this.

Comment: @PeterM - Websters dictionary defines 'begging the question' as *"to elicit a specific question as a reaction or response"*, which is precisely the way it's been used. If that upsets you, I'd suggest you also not look up the words irony or literally

Comment: @Valorum [Irregardless](https://www.bostonglobe.com/2021/06/04/opinion/losing-battles-with-language/) of that, there are a plethora of such problematic constructions  :D

Comment: @Spencer - a lot of people mistake the dictionary as a cage for language instead of a record of its use.